# Can you get a custom action by clicking an HTML link in a TextView?

Tags: android, android-intent, textview

I'd like to have an `HTML` link in a `TextView` start an activity in my app.

There are plenty of answers about how to do this, but it seems that most of them end up using a non-standard `URI` scheme (such as the package name) and catching an ACTION_VIEW for this.

There are also plenty of answers in a slightly different context saying don't do this... there is already a perfectly good intent URI scheme in Android, and you can define custom actions within that scheme.

My problem is that I can't put the two together, in that all that I can convince clicking on an HTML link in a `TextView` to do is generate an `ACTION_VIEW`.  Is there any way to get an intent with a custom action here?

**EDIT**
OK, the TextView is assigned a Spannable that has a URLSpan for each ....  And URLSpan has:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View widget) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(getURL());
    Context context = widget.getContext();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    intent.putExtra(Browser.EXTRA_APPLICATION_ID, context.getPackageName());
    try {
        context.startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Log.w("URLSpan", "Actvity was not found for intent, " + intent.toString());
    }
}
```

So yeah, looks like I'm stuck with a VIEW action.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: Using Clickable span you can get click on a part of text . If that's what you need to do .

Comment: I've got a *lot* of html though.  I'd rather not write custom code to get links... much better to change the <a href="..."> to whatever it needs to be in order to get my intent.  Anyway getting *a* click is no problem... I just would prefer it to not be a VIEW action.

Comment: Are you able to manipulate your HTML text before applying it to a `TextView`? If so, can you use the `String::replace` function to swap out existing link addresses to point to somewhere else?

Comment: I can edit the links to be whatever I want them to be.  I'd like them to be an "intent:#Intent;blahblahblah;end" type of URL.  My problem is that even after I do this, and the intent link specifies an action, I only get a VIEW action when the link is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, would require rewriting too much low-level code.